# Botão que quando clicado mostra apenas o conteúdo de determinada classe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Olá,
Estou criando um sistema em Javascript, onde preciso que um botão mostre apenas os parágrafos com determinada classe em uma div com conteúdo escondido.

Exemplo:

```
 <button id="btn1">Abre classe1</button>
 <div id="conteudo">
     <p class="classe1">Teste1</p>
     <p class="classe1">Teste2</p>
     <p class="classe2">Teste3</p>
 </div>
```

Gostaria que quando esse botão fosse clicado, a div carregasse apenas o texto  Teste1 e Teste2.
É possível?

Obrigada.

Comment: O que quer dizer com "mostre apenas"? Esse conteudo vai estar escondido? ou deve ser mostrado noutro elemento?

Comment: Isto, é uma div com conteúdo escondido.

Comment: O que está escondido, a div inteira ou o que está dentro dela? Pode incluir essa parte do seu CSS na pergunta?

Answer (score 3):

Para mostrar esses elementos com a classe que quer pode usar assim: http://jsfiddle.net/caYtr/

```
$('#btn1').on('click', function(){
    $('#conteudo p.classe1').show();
});
```

Estou a assumir que tem um CSS assim:

```
#conteudo p {
    display: none;
}
```

Porém seria util adicionar mais informação a esse `button` para criar código mais generalista e não tão localizado, no caso de haver botôes que mostrem outras classes.

Podia por exemplo juntar um campo `data-classe` onde juntava o nome exato da classe que esse botão devia mostrar.

Assim: http://jsfiddle.net/caYtr/2/

HTML

```
<button id="btn1" data-classe="classe1">Abre classe1</button>
<button id="btn2" data-classe="classe2">Abre classe2</button>
<div id="conteudo">
    <p class="classe1">Teste1</p>
    <p class="classe1">Teste2</p>
    <p class="classe2">Teste3</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript/jQuery

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var classe = $(this).data('classe');
    $('#conteudo p.' + classe).show();
});
```

E neste caso o javascript não precisa mais de mudar, independentemente de ter mais 20 classes diferentes.

Answer (score 2):

Se todo conteúdo fica oculto e é exibido somente no click do botão, você pode fazer

**Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LGaqe/1/)**

Exemplo:

**CSS**

```
/*oculta todos os parágrafos dentro da div conteúdo*/
#conteudo p {display:none;}
```

**jQuery**

```
//Ao clicar no botão com id #btn1, exibe os parágrafos com .classe1
$('#btn1').click(function(){
    $('p.classe1').show('slow');
});
```